# Change JSON format in JavaScript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I need to change JSON format by JavaScript or C#...
The method in code behind that generate JSON data is like this:

```
  public string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(DataTable table)
        {
            var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                JSONString.Append("[");
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("{");
                    for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
                        }
                        else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
                        }
                    }
                    if (i == table.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("},");
                    }
                }
                JSONString.Append("]");
            }
            return JSONString.ToString();
        }
```

I access the method through jQuery AJAX

```
  var tahun = $("#<%=txbTahun.ClientID %>").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ProjMonitor/Report/ProjectMonitoringSummary.aspx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{tahun:" + tahun + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
           var dataLevel = JSON.stringify(msg);
        //   alert(dataLevel);
           ShowData(dataLevel,'');
        },
        error: function (msg) {

        }
    });
```

Then the output (dataLevel) turnsout to be like this:

```
   {d:[
    {
        "1332879360000.0": 300,
        "1332797760000.0": 353,
        "1332799320000.0": 358,
        "1332879780000.0": 302,
        "1332800160000.0": 359,
        "1332880200000.0": 299,
        "1332880620000.0": 298,
        "1332881040000.0": 301,
        "1332881460000.0": 402,
        "1332880020000.0": 330,
        "1332882300000.0": 466,
        "1332796620000.0": 519,
        "1332800520000.0": 447,
        "1332797460000.0": 359,
        "1332801000000.0": 442
    },
{
        "1332879360000.0": 300,
        "1332797760000.0": 353,
        "1332799320000.0": 358,
        "1332879780000.0": 302,
        "1332800160000.0": 359,
        "1332880200000.0": 299,
        "1332880620000.0": 298,
        "1332881040000.0": 301,
        "1332881460000.0": 402,
        "1332880020000.0": 330,
        "1332882300000.0": 466,
        "1332796620000.0": 519,
        "1332800520000.0": 447,
        "1332797460000.0": 359,
        "1332801000000.0": 442
    }

]}
```

I need the format to be like this... What should I change or what JavaScript function that can convert it?

```
    [
    {
        "1332879360000.0": 300,
        "1332797760000.0": 353,
        "1332799320000.0": 358,
        "1332879780000.0": 302,
        "1332800160000.0": 359,
        "1332880200000.0": 299,
        "1332880620000.0": 298,
        "1332881040000.0": 301,
        "1332881460000.0": 402,
        "1332880020000.0": 330,
        "1332882300000.0": 466,
        "1332796620000.0": 519,
        "1332800520000.0": 447,
        "1332797460000.0": 359,
        "1332801000000.0": 442
    }, 
{
        "1332879360000.0": 300,
        "1332797760000.0": 353,
        "1332799320000.0": 358,
        "1332879780000.0": 302,
        "1332800160000.0": 359,
        "1332880200000.0": 299,
        "1332880620000.0": 298,
        "1332881040000.0": 301,
        "1332881460000.0": 402,
        "1332880020000.0": 330,
        "1332882300000.0": 466,
        "1332796620000.0": 519,
        "1332800520000.0": 447,
        "1332797460000.0": 359,
        "1332801000000.0": 442
    }
]
```

Comment: solved... i access it thru msg.d

Comment: Ajax request always returns with "d" object so i suggest doing JSON.stringify(msg.d);

Comment: @user1851384 , if you have solved the problem. Post it as an answer, so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an object returned, with a property `d` holding the array you want. To get the array, just do `dataLevel.d`.

So...

```
  var tahun = $("#<%=txbTahun.ClientID %>").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ProjMonitor/Report/ProjectMonitoringSummary.aspx/GetData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{tahun:" + tahun + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
       var dataLevel = JSON.stringify(msg);
    //   alert(dataLevel.d);
       ShowData(dataLevel.d,'');
    },
    error: function (msg) {

    }
});
```